# Set state separately for each ListView element. Flutter

Tags: flutter, state, flutter-listview, animatedcontainer

Every element of my ListView is AnimatedContainer

```
AnimatedContainer(
height: _height,
...)
```

While changing _height via setState it works for every ListView element of course.

```
    Future<void> _changeHeight() async {
     setState(() {
      _height = 2;
    });}
```

How to set _height separately for each element AnimatedContainer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of a `_height` variable of type double, use a key/value map with the keys as the list item's index and the value as its height

```dart
Map<int, double> heights = {};
```

To use the height:

```dart
AnimatedContainer(
   height: heights[index]!,
   //...
)
```

And to set the height:

```dart
Future<void> _changeHeight() async {
  setState(() {
    heights[index] = 2;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a single variable to all the list elements as it's height! So, if you change it, all of them will be changed, beacause they are actually a single variable.
The solution is one of these:

1. Define a list of doubles or a map that includes the height of every element seperately.
2. Use an invisible container for the rest of your item, and a list of booleans, when the item is tapped, set state corresponding boolean to true, and change the visibility of that invisible container.